# Executing code after calling dynamic number of functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm only crawling in JS so probably the solution is obvious.

I'm writing a Chrome extension which in browser action (after clicking on extension's button) reads several pages and from each of them it retrieves an integer. Then, it creates a table with these integers. I'm doing it qith AJAX so it's asynchronous and I want to have all integers before creating the table.

I've read these topics:

- [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)
- [How to tell when multiple functions have completed with jQuery deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356601/how-to-tell-when-multiple-functions-have-completed-with-jquery-deferred)

...and wrote a code that doesn't work.

```
var sum = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var deferreds = [];
    var users = [...], pages = [...];
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < pages.length; ++j)
            deferreds.push(window[pages[j]](users[i], pages[j]));
    }
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
        alert("sum: " + sum);
    });
});

function Name(user, page) {
    $.get("http://page2/" + user, function(data) {
        sum += 7;
    });
    return 7;
}

function Name2(user, page) {
    $.get("http://page/" + user, function(data) {
        sum += 84;
    });
    return 84;
}
```

So the alert prints 0 instead of 91. I cut the part with table as all fields are "undefined" anyway. If I get sum = 91, I'll probably get the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said - obvious mistake. The functions should look like:

```
function Name(user, page) {
    return $.get("http://page2/" + user, function(data) {
        sum += 7;
    });
}
```